# For each instance of array-item in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check for each instance of all array-items in a string. Example;

```
var string = "aa bb ccc";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

This should execute my code 7 times - once for each instance of any array-item being in the string. This is quite hard to explain, but I hope the example is enough.

Another explained-code example;

```
$.each(ArrayItem in string) {
    //execute code
}
```

I cannot get my head around this one, and haven't yet found anything that remotely works the way I want it to.

**Edit**

I want to use this to add a price for each letter - say "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" costs $1, while the rest costs $2 - I would need to check for each instance of the array-items above in my string, and calculate the price.

Comment: `string` is your input and you need `array` ?

Comment: Did you try looking at REGEX? That would be 1000 times faster than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, @Weedoze, the string is the input field and the array contains the items I want to check for.

Comment: what do you do with space? does it count? for some value?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use while+exec inside of for-loop over array items:

```js
var string = "aa bb ass ccc ass"
var array = ["ass", "b", "c"]

var m

array.forEach(function(item) {
  var reg = RegExp(item, 'g')
  while ((m = reg.exec(string)) !== null) {
    console.log('match', m[0])
  }
})
```

Comment: Yep it's much better indeed. +1

Comment: What if you had `a` in the array as well?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Then `a` from array will also be counted in `ass` from `string`. It's not clear what is the behavior OP expects in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Split your `string` using `spread operator` and iterate over it to check if `array` contains any of the elements from that array.

```js
var string = "aa bb ccc";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

[...string].forEach(v => array.some(function(c){
  if (c == v) {
    console.log('code executed');
  }
}));
```

Comment: You can also try `v=>array.includes(v) && process(v)`

Comment: Nope, not reliable. You assumed that string consists of charactes, but OP meant "strings".

Comment: @dfsq Can you provide me some counter example?

Comment: For example: `var string = "ass bb ccc"; var array = ["ass", "b", "c"];` there should be `6` code invocations, but your version will yield only 5 because `ass` will not be found.

Comment: @dfsq Hold on will look at it.

Comment: How do I get the count of this? I would be running this code constantly, and I only want it to go through all of them once, do its thing then not run it anymore until the input has changed.

Comment: Sure, look at it. But you will not be able to split by character like you are doing right now. Check my answer for possible approach. You could also try to split by regexp, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the string by `' '` to get an array of substrings, and then use `forEach` or `$.each` to loop throught them like:

Spliting:

```
var strings = string.split(' ');
```

or more effectivelly:

```
var strings = string.trim()         // remove sorrounding spaces
                    .split(/\s+/);  // split by any number of spaces
```

Looping using `forEach`:

```
strings.forEach(function(str) {
    // use str
});
```

Looping using `$.each`:

```
$.each(strings, function(i, str) {
    // use str
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will do your work

```
    function checkString(a){
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {  
          if(a[i]!==" "){
            if (yourArray.indexOf(a[i]) > -1) {
                //this line executes 7 times if the string a has 7 characters;
            } 
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object and count the appearances of the letters. Later, you could separate by different priced values.

```js
var string = "aa bb ccc xyz",
    array = ["a", "b", "c"],
    count = Object.create(null);

string.split('').forEach(function (a) {
    if (a !== ' ') {
        count[a] = (count[a] || 0) + 1;
    }
});

Object.keys(count).forEach(function (k) {
    if (array.indexOf(k) !== -1) {
        console.log('found ' + k + ' of array: ' + count[k] + ' times');
    } else {
        console.log('found ' + k + ': ' + count[k] + ' times');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you are answering what OP asked.

Comment: could be, who knows.

Comment: No, and the code snippet also only output one console log.

Comment: @iversen, please add some more examples **and** the wanted output.

Comment: Gotcha, @NinaScholz adding them now

Comment: Updated, @NinaScholz but I think my example explained it as well as I can. I added a brief description of how I want to use this though, which might help a little.

Comment: @iversen, maybe you could use a more real example and the wanted output of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` method with " " parameter.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var string = "aa bb ccc",
    array = string.split(" ");
```

Or you can also used lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#split